# activeCollab: Failed to connect. Reason: Failed to load class 'Swift_1_SimpleCharacterReaderFactory'

Tags: activecollab

**Details:** 
I am using activeCollab, have installed it on cPanel shared server.
Unable to send emails via native php mail function, even if i try to configure STMP i get the error. so i am not able to configure SMTP either.
Not sure where i am going wrong.

**Version:** 
3.2.12

**Error:** 
Failed to connect. Reason: Failed to load class 'Swift_1_SimpleCharacterReaderFactory'
Failed to send message. Reason: Failed to load class 'Swift_1_SimpleCharacterReaderFactory'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a known issue, so we recommend that you upgrade to the latest stable release (3.3.18 at the moment). You can find the upgrade instructions [here](http://www.activecollab.com/docs/manuals/admin-version-3/upgrade/latest-stable).

Upgrade should resolve the potential problem that you did not upload all the files properly, plus activeCollab 3.3 has auto-upgrade feature which will make similar error less likely to happen in the future.